# Changing paragraph content with button

Tags: innerhtml

Forgive my ignorance, because I'm pretty new to programing. I've been beating out my brains on this one. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work? I know it will be something dumb:

```js
        addText(){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "New Content";
            }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>InnerHTML Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p id="demo">
                <Button onclick="addText()">Change</Button>
                Original Content
            </p>
           
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared `addTest()` as a function. Should be:

```
<script>
  function addTest() {
...
} 
</script>
```

```js
function addText() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "New Content";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>InnerHTML Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="demo">
    <Button onclick="addText()">Change</Button> Original Content
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here's a tool for testing it out, too:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp